# Toggle html validation globally

Tags: symfony, twig

I've made a couple of twig extensions but I'm stumped on this one.

I have the following template logic that I want to make into an extension.

I need reuse this logic into many different forms instead of copying and pasting the following code everywhere:

```
{% if html5validation is not defined %}
    {{ form_start(some_form) }}
{% else %}
    {% if html5validation %}
        {{ form_start(some_form) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ form_start
            (
                company, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}
            ) 
        }}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

With the above code from the controller I can do the following to turn the html5 validator on and off:

```
$this->render(..., array(html5validation => false));
```

I want put the template logic into the twig extension below...

I just don't know if it's possible to implement what I've done above in a twig extension.

```
class HTML5Validation extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('html5validation', array($this, 'setValidation')),
        );
    }

    public function setValidation($boolean)
    {
        //Implement the same logic as the twig template.
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'html5validator';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a better way to do what I wanted.

As a plus it works globally instead of having to populate more fields into your controller!

In **YourBundle/Resources/views/validation.toggle.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form_start -%}
    {% if html5validation is defined and html5validation == false %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'novalidate': 'novalidate'}) %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ parent() }}
{%- endblock form_start %}
```

Then if you want to turn off html5 validation across the whole website:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    global:
        html5validation: false
```

**Or**

Even better just use it in your `dev_config.yml` if you want validation on by default on production mode but the ability to toggle validation on and off for dev mode.

```
# app/config/dev_config.yml
twig:
    global:
        html5validation: false
    resources:
        - 'YourBundle::validation.toggle.html.twig'
```

Finally use it in your twig template normally:

```
{% form_theme your_form 'YourBundle::validation.toggle.html.twig' %}

form_start(your_form)
```

Reusable and non invasive, exactly like I wanted it. :)

I got the hint from:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11409#issuecomment-49358377

Comment: Can I suggest you make your questions less specific in future, i.e. more about what you are trying to achieve than how to make something work in a specific way. I could have given you this answer much sooner and with less effort on my part if I'd known what it was you were actually trying to do!

Comment: I actually didn't know this was what I wanted myself. I just wanted it on to be easier a use per basis. Then I thought why not just turn it off and on on everything whenever I want? This was all the process to figure it out and you were part of it, thanks for your time I really appreciate it :) Plus not one of your efforts are wasted, your other answers will help some poor soul to figure out something similar but not exactly like my answer I bet.

Comment: Looking back on it you're right, I had been working on this for a while so I think my brain was just burnt out a little. Sorry about that!

Comment: Caution: If you use other form themes as well, the line `{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}` (in the above code) will override them. Solution: 1) Load your theme globally in config.yml. 2) Put `{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}` into your theme. 3) In validation.toggle.html.twig use this instead: `{% extends 'your_theme.html.twig' %}`

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no - you can't do this using a twig extension, it's not what they're meant for.

Looking at your template fragment I'd say you need to customise the form_start block. To do this see [Symfony Form Theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming) and [How to customise form rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

EDIT: This solution does not work if your customised code requires local twig variables - only global twig variables are available for form theming. You can define your own twig globals in config.yml or in a twig extension.

For example, to override form_start globally, you find the default definition of the form_start block in [form_div_layout.html.twig](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig), copy it into your own form theme file e.g. YourBundle/Form/fields.html.twig, modify it as required and and update the twig configuration to apply your form theme file. Something like this:

```
{# src/YourBundle/Form/fields.html.twig #}
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form_start -%}
    {% if html5validation is not defined %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% else %}
        {% if html5validation %}
            {{ parent() }}
        {% else %}
            {{ parent
                (
                    company, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}
                ) 
            }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{%- endblock form_start %}
```

Config:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'YourBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

Comment: Ah, I knew something was off. Totally went over my head to use theme overriding! :D Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look like I can use this with form_theme? I get the error `html5validation variable doesn't exist.`

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I didn't realise only global twig variables can be used in form theming. For specific field types it is possible to pass variables into form theming by using a FormExtension (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html). However, I tried this with type 'form' and couldn't get it to work. I suggest you update your question to say you tried to use theme overriding but it didn't work because html5validation is not a global variable. Then I can delete this answer, which I think should deduct the points.

Comment: Don't delete your answer by the way, leave it so that I can reference or others can :) Although do leave a note that we figured out it isn't possible :( Might save others time.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, found the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a more elegant solution, you can always put the twig fragment given in your question into a separate file and use [twig include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) from your various forms. The included fragment has access to the variables from the surrounding context:

```
{# YourBundle/Resources/views/form_start.html.twig #}
{% if html5validation is not defined %}
    {{ form_start(some_form) }}
{% else %}
    {% if html5validation %}
        {{ form_start(some_form) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ form_start
            (
                company, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}
            ) 
        }}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Then in the twig file for the form:

```
{% include 'YourBundle::form_start.html.twig' %}
```

If you typically pass a 'form' variable into render() in your controller(s) then you can use that in your form_start fragment. Otherwise you can pass the appropriate form in as a variable:

```
{% include 'YourBundle::form_start.html.twig' with {'form': localForm} %}
```

Comment: OH MY GOSH THE `WITH` KEYWORD IS AMAZING! Was really looking for that as well. Thank you! You really hit two birds with one stone :)