# Twig variable doesn't exist in form_theme

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to override default Symfony2 form to implement the code below that will allow me to turn off html5 validation on and off by just passing a variable.

**html5validation.toggle.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form_start -%}
        {% if html5validation %}
            {{ parent() }}
        {% else %}
            {{ parent
                (
                    companyform, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}
                ) 
            }}
        {% endif %}
{%- endblock form_start %}
```

**index.html.twig**

```
form_theme company_form 'AcmeDemoBundle:html5validation.toggle.html.twig'

form(companyform)
```

In my controller I have:

```
 $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Index:index.html.twig', array('html5validation' => false, 'companyform' => ...
```

If I try to `dump(html5validation)` inside `index.html.twig` I get `bool(false)`.

But when I try to include the `form_theme company_form AcmeDemoBundle:html5validation.toggle.html.twig`

I get the error:

**Variable "html5validation" does not exist**

Can controller variables not be used inside themes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out only global variables are allowed to be used in `form_theme`(s) :(

[Toggle html validation globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766672/trouble-making-template-logic-into-a-twig-extension/24770178?noredirect=1#comment38496983_24770178)